# Probability of limit of discrete uniform r.v.

Tags: probability

Let $\mathrm{X}_{\mathrm{1}}=1$ and $\mathrm{X}_{\mathrm{i}}, 1<\mathrm{i}<=\mathrm{N}$, be $\mathrm{N}$ independent and uniformly distributed random variables over the set $\{1 / \mathrm{i}, 2 / \mathrm{i}, \ldots,(\mathrm{i}-1) / \mathrm{i}\} .$ As $\mathrm{N}$ tends towards infinity,what is the probability that $\mathrm{N} * \min \left(\mathrm{X}_{1}, \mathrm{X}_{2}, \ldots, \mathrm{X}_{N}\right)$ is greater than 2018?

Tentative solution:
$P\left(N\min \left(X_{1}, \ldots, X_{N}\right) > 2018\right) = P\left(\min \left(X_{1}, \ldots, X_{N}\right)>\frac{2018}{N}\right) \\
= P(X_{1}>\frac{2018}{N}, \ldots, X_{N}>\frac{2018}{N}) = P(X_{1}>\frac{2018}{N}) \ldots P\left(X_{N}>\frac{2018}{N}\right)$

I am not sure on how to deal with $\lim_{N\to\infty} P(X_{1}>\frac{2018}{N}) \ldots P\left(X_{N}>\frac{2018}{N}\right)$

Comment: Hint: the variable $\min X_j$ has an easy to find CDF.

Comment: If they were i.i.d. the cdf woul be $1-\left[1-F_{X}(y)\right]^{n}$ but the sets on which the variables are defined are different.

Comment: From your definition $X_2$ takes on the value $1/2$ with probability $1$.  What value or values (if any) does $X_1$ take?  Or does $i$ start at $2$?  Or does $X_1$ take on the value $0$ with probability $1$?

Comment: If $X_1=0$ with probability 1, then the probability that $Z=N \min(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_N)$ is greater than 2018 is zero because $Z=0$ with probability 1.

Comment: No, the set is correct like this. $X_{2}$ can take both values $1$ and $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Something is missing here, $X_1$ is ill defined, as the set of values is **empty** (it runs from $1/1$ to $0/1$) and as written $X_2$ takes the value $1/2$ with probability 1.

Comment: I understand your points now. I agree that the problem was not well defined, I think it was meant to be such that the r.v. $X_{1}=1$ with probability $1$ and the r.v. $X_{2}=\frac{1}{2}$ with probability $1$, this would make the problem well defined I think.

Comment: I think there's still some work to do.  For example, if $i=5$, the probability that $X_5 > 2018/N$ is zero for $5\leq N \leq  2522$.  Same thing for many values of $i<N$ so the probability that $N \min(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ is greater than $2018/N$ is zero for any value of $N$.  (But maybe I'll still not understanding the set-up.)

Comment: But the probability is asked for the limit then $\lim_{N\to\infty} P(X_5 > 2018/N)=1$ and I would like to say that $\forall i \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: I understand and agree with that limit for a specific $i$.  But for any finite $N$ the probability of $N \min(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_N) > 2018$ is zero.  But maybe my memory about limits faded long ago.

Comment: Not sure if it is for any finite $N$, for example the probability for $X_{i}$ becomes $1$ for $N>2018i$

Comment: You're right.  I didn't try large enough values of $N$.  I'll try to do better in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited to correct the distribution for $i=2$**

The following is simply a numerical exercise to see what a plausible limit might be for $\text{Pr}(N \times \min(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_N) > 2018)$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$.

As shown in your question we need first to find $\text{Pr}(X_i > 2018/N)$.  For $i=1$ that is

$$\begin{equation*}
 \text{Pr}(X_1>2018/N) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
  0 & N\leq 2018 \\
  1 & N>2018 \\
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation*}$$

For $i=2$ that probability is

$$\begin{equation*}
 \text{Pr}(X_2>2018/N) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{cc}
  0 & N\leq 4036 \\
   1 & N>4036 \\
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation*}
$$

And for $i\geq 3$ that probability is

$$\begin{equation*}
 \text{Pr}(X_i>2018/N) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{cc}
  0 & N\geq i (N-2018) \\
    1-\frac{\left\lfloor \frac{2018 i}{N}\right\rfloor }{i-1} & 2018 i\geq N\text{ and } i   (N-2018)>N \\
    1 & N > 2018i \\
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation*}$$

The product of the probabilities is zero for $N\leq 4036$ and positive for all larger values of $N$.  That will be a very small number which is generally too small to represent as a floating point number so we look at the log of the product.

Using *Mathematica* here are the formulas for the individual probabilities:

```
pr[1, n] := 1 - CDF[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 1}], 2018/n]
pr[i_, n_] := 1 - CDF[TransformedDistribution[x/i, 
    x \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, i - 1}]], 2018/n]
```

(Note that $N$ is a reserved symbol in *Mathematica* so I've changed that to $n$.)

Generate several values of the desired log of the probability and plot the results:

```
data = Table[{n, Log[Product[pr[i, n], {i, 1, n}]] // N}, {n, 4000, 100000, 1000}]
```

[image: Plot of N vs probability]

Fitting a particular model to the observations results in the following:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a + (b + c x + d x^2)/(x + e x^2), {a, b, c, d, e}, x,
  MaxIterations -> 5000]
```

[image: Data and fit with asymptotic value]

The red line is the value of the limit of the estimated prediction equation as $N\rightarrow \infty$:

```
Limit[nlm // Normal, x -> ∞]
(* -2013.21 *)
```

which corresponds to a probability of $10^{-874.326}$.

**Why is $4036$ the minimum value of $N$ to consider?**

$\text{Pr}(X_1>2018/N)=0$ for $N\leq2018$.

$\text{Pr}(X_2>2018/N)=0$ for $N\leq4036$.

$\text{Pr}(X_3>2018/N)=0$ for $N\leq3027$.

$\text{Pr}(X_4>2018/N)=0$ for $N\leq2690$.

$\text{Pr}(X_5>2018/N)=0$ for $N\leq2522$.

$\text{Pr}(X_6>2018/N)=0$ for $N\leq2054$.

So we see that a value of $N$ less than or equal to 4036 will result in at least one of the individual probabilities being zero which means, of course, that the product of all of those probabilities will be zero.

The full set of values for $X_3$ follows:

$$\begin{equation*}
 \text{Pr}(X_3>2018/N) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{cc}
   0 & N\leq 3027 \\
   \frac{1}{2} & 3027<N\leq 6054 \\
   1 & N>6054 \\
 \end{array}\right.
\end{equation*}$$

Comment: I am not too conviced about the condition for the probability equal to $1$ in the general $i$, I think the term $(i-1)N$ should be just $N$, and also maybe a strict inequality?

Comment: Sorry, my attempt by hand to rearrange that piece from what *Mathematica* gave went astray.  Thanks.  I've corrected that.  That formula was only for display.  I used the functions from *Mathematica* untouched to obtain the probabilities.

Comment: Can you explain further why the product of probabilities is $0$ for $N \le 3027$?

Comment: I've messed up the distribution for $X_2$ as it (like $X_1$) must be a constant taking the value $1/2$.  I'll edit this answer correcting things and giving a better explanation for what the new minimum for $N$ must be.